# which location store the data in rabbitmq and which file format?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

In kafka data store on topic and in local directory but in rabbitMQ which location and which file format data is stored. and how to check in UI of rabbitMQ please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq usues `Mnesia` database to store the broker definitions and a custom db to store the messages.

See the location here:https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html

it usually you can find the database messages here:

`/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbitmq@hostname/queues/`

each directory is a queue